# SQL to bring back material names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The below code is a result of a query i have created, it all works fine apart from one thing.  I have Material ID's for material names:

```
1 = bath
2 = sink
3 = toilet
```

The below works but displays sink for every material

```
Select cu.FName + '  ' + cu.SName as 'Name', 
cu.Address1 + ', ' + cu.Address2 + ', ' + cu.Address3 as 'Dispatch Address', 
cu.PostCode, 
co.DateOrdered,
co.Material1,
ma.MaterialName,
co.material2, 
ma.MaterialName, 
ma.Price as 'Item Price' 
from Customers cu 
left join CustomerOrder co on co.CustomerID = cu.CustomerID
left join ItemOrder it on it.OrderID = co.OrderID 
left join Materials ma on ma.MaterialID = co.Material1 
or co.material2 = ma.MaterialItemID or co.material3 = ma.MaterialItemID
```

it displays as follows (just the materials are listed to stop confusion)

```
Material1 | MaterialName | Material2 | Material2Name | Material3 | Material3Name
    1          Sink            2           Sink           3             Sink
```

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can do this including using `JOIN` on the `materials` table multiple times to get the result:

```
Select cu.FName + '  ' + cu.SName as 'Name', 
    cu.Address1 + ', ' + cu.Address2 + ', ' + cu.Address3 as 'Dispatch Address', 
    cu.PostCode, 
    co.DateOrdered,
    co.Material1,
    ma1.MaterialName Material1Name,
    co.material2, 
    ma2.MaterialName Material2Name, 
    ma1.Price as 'Item Price',
    co.material3, 
    ma3.MaterialName  Material3Name
from Customers cu 
left join CustomerOrder co 
    on co.CustomerID = cu.CustomerID
left join ItemOrder it 
    on it.OrderID = co.OrderID 
left join Materials ma1 
    on ma1.MaterialID = co.Material1 
left join Materials ma2 
    on co.material2 = ma2.MaterialItemID
left join Materials ma3 
    on co.material3 = ma3.MaterialItemID
```

Comment: one more question, how would i sum up values of the materials Id's? instead of having the ma1.price as 'item price' can i just create a line that adds up 3 price valued together?

Comment: It sounds like you can use (ma1.price + ma2.price + ma3.price) to get the total price of the items.